# AJAX call without Java application context

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring

I have a (Spring-powered) Java application that has a some AJAX calls. The problem is that I'm using the application context (`/spring-mvc`) to be able to reach the server-side functionality.

```
var api = '/api/v1';
var context = '/spring-mvc' + api;

$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: context + '/users/' + $('#user-id').val()
}).done(function (response) {
  callback({ data: response.user, binding: response.binding });
}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  callback({ jqXHR: jqXHR });
});
```

Now, my problem is whenever I have to deploy it somewhere else, and I can't control the application context, the AJAX calls are eventually failing since the application context itself is hard-coded in the JavaScript.

Is there any way to achieve this without having to change the `context` variable in all JavaScript files? Something like:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/api/v1/users/' + $('#user-id').val()
}).done(function (response) {
  callback({ data: response.user, binding: response.binding });
}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  callback({ jqXHR: jqXHR });
});
```

I've seen that several times in many applications, but I can't figure it out how they do that.

**Note:** The Web application is deployed in the same WAR file; I would like to avoid to try to figure it out by doing URL manipulation in JavaScript.

Comment: `/api/v1/` is usually the equivalent to the context-path in Spring, whats your question=

Comment: Yes, but if I don't prepend the application context to the `url` in the AJAX calls, it also fails. I want a way to get the application context dynamically (or some sort of)

Answer (score 1):

Deadly simple, you may include the context with a hidden input, such as

```
<input type="hidden" id="ctx" name="ctx" value="<applciation_context_here>"/>
```

then in your js

```
var context = document.getElementById("ctx").value/*getAttribute('value')*/ + api;
```

---

or better way acquire the current windows location(path), and some string manipulation to get the context

---

update0:

**FACTS:**

Let say you will have `/a` , `/b` and `/c` contexts, I don't know but usually they will be mapped to `a.com` , `b.com` and `c.com` and context will be identified by the server as requested host, such as following

```
a.com -> local_host/a
b.com -> local_host/b
```

But if you are not going as above, as you are generating the jsp file, you may set the context path as hidden input approach

Comment: I'm trying not to do URL manipulation here, although it's also valid; the approach with the hidden field is the same like having a variable `context` in the JavaScript files

Comment: wonder what is the problem with url manipulation! the more logical way would be domain mapping with the context(check the update)

Comment: OK, maybe I forgot this: we are not using any server-side technology, just plain HTML, otherwise getting the application context would be trivial. When I say "application context", is not the domain, but the piece of the URL your application is running on; usually what comes after the `<domain>:<port>`, e.g. `http://the-world:9080/application-context/api/v1`